# how to disable dart:mirrors warning messages during test compilation for chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, dart, angular-dart

I'm using dart:mirrors in my project because I need reflection capabilities. 
Since mirrors are experimental, I was receiving the usual warning telling me that.
I've been able to disable these warnings during a `pub build` by adding the transformer:

```
- $dart2js:
    commandLineOptions: [--enable-experimental-mirrors]
```

to my `pubspec.yaml`, however, since I need to test the build on chrome, I still receive the warning message when I execute the test command

```
pub run test -p chrome
```

Apparently the build triggered by `pub run test` is ignoring my pubspec.
Is there a way to eliminate the wranings even on the test? is it a bug?